# Maintaining State When Changing Routes in AngularjS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.0 and need to maintain state (user-entered data) on a page even when the user navigates (angular routing) to another page and then comes back to the original page. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

From what I've read online, the solution is to use a service/factory to store the data. Here is a snippet of my implementation (notice the comments; they address my concern):

```
    function cassetteController($scope, $rootScope, $http, $timeout, cassetteRepository) {
        // Need to get state from repository in case the user is coming back to this page.
        // This means every time we add some variable to our controller, we have to remember to include it here.
        $scope.userEnteredSubId = cassetteRepository.userEnteredSubId;
        $scope.cassettes = cassetteRepository.cassettes;
        $scope.numberOfCassettesToShow = cassetteRepository.numberOfCassettesToShow;
        $scope.subId1 = cassetteRepository.subId1;
        $scope.subId2 = cassetteRepository.subId2;
        $scope.subId3 = cassetteRepository.subId3;

        // Every time we alter a $scope variable, we have to remember to also alter the state in the factory.
        // This seems error-prone and tedious. Each line below is followed by a line that stores its
        // value in the factory. 
        $scope.onClickCassette = function (cassette) {
            $scope.subId1 = cassette._content[0].SolarPanel.SubId;
            cassetteRepository.subId1 = cassette._content[0].SolarPanel.SubId;
            $scope.subId2 = cassette._content[1].SolarPanel.SubId;
            cassetteRepository.subId2 = cassette._content[1].SolarPanel.SubId;
            $scope.subId3 = cassette._content[2].SolarPanel.SubId;
            cassetteRepository.subId3 = cassette._content[2].SolarPanel.SubId;
        }
}
```

And here is the factory that stores the state:

```
app.factory('cassetteRepository', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var state = {
        userEnteredSubId: '',
        cassettes: [],
        numberOfCassettesToShow: 10,
        subId1: '',
        subId2: '',
        subId3: ''
    }

    return state;
}]);
```

My question is this: Really? It seems like there has to be a more elegant approach. I've only shown a portion of my controller. Every time I set a variable, I have to remember to set its counterpart in the factory where the state is maintained. Am I missing something? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this *only* to save values then I would use a value instead of creating a service. Here is how you set up a value in Angular:

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
    .value('cassetteRepository', { data: {} });
```

Now you can inject that value and use its data property directly so you don't have to update things twice. Here's how to use it in a controller:

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
    .controller('yourControllerName', ['$scope', 'cassetteRepository', function($scope, cassetteRepository) {
        // create a local scope reference if you need to use this in your view
        $scope.cassetteRepository = cassetteRepository;

        // now when you set properties on $scope.cassetteRepository.data they are set on
        // the value and are persisted and shared across your app.
        // you can also use ng-model to two-way bind in your view.
        $scope.onClickCassette = function (cassette) {
            $scope.cassetteRepository.data.subId1 = cassette._content[0].SolarPanel.SubId;
            $scope.cassetteRepository.data.subId2 = cassette._content[1].SolarPanel.SubId;
            $scope.cassetteRepository.data.subId3 = cassette._content[2].SolarPanel.SubId;
        };
});
```

You don't have to use the `data` object in your value. You could also just define the properties directly. E.g.:

```
.value('cassetteRepository', { userEnteredSubId = "", cassettes = [], numberOfCassettesToShow = 10, etc. })
```

That way you can provide default values and eliminate having the `.data` part.

Comment: Ooooooh, I like this. So my view would then reference the properties in the repository property on $scope, right? Let me give this a shot...

Comment: Exactly. The view doesn't have access to the value directly which is why you have to put it in a `$scope` property.

Comment: Actually, this same concept worked by just setting my existing cassetteRepository as a property on scope. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I totally spaced that you were already setting that and returning state. D'oh! My bad.

Comment: Well, it was the concept that I needed. This will save me a ton of tedious effort over the life of this web site. Appreciate it!